# Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, how do I get a Worksheet object from its CodeName?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a C# XLL (Excel add-in) to get data from another application and drop it into standardised output tables in Excel. To do this, I have a 'template' output Worksheet in Excel that I need to grab and copy as many times as required for a particular call (I write multiple sheets of data each time, depending on the other application settings etc.).

I know I can loop through all Worksheets in the Workbook and compare the CodeName property until I get a match, but this is clunky - is there a way to directly address the object by name via Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel?

Comment: Yes if you know the name of the worksheet.  Do you know the name?  You are making copies of a worksheet and the name of the worksheet is then generated by excel.  I usually specify to copy to end of workbook.  Then get the number of worksheets in the workbook.  The new worksheet is the last index of the workbook.  Once you know the index number you can get the name from the index.

Comment: See my answer below - I tweaked it a little, but ended up looping through all sheets because I need to anyway, in case the code has already run once and the target sheets already exist. I also had to Copy the template sheet *before* itself, as it is hidden, so I had to fiddle with those lines until it was robust to the final sheet in the workbook being hidden.

Comment: I do not like copying before because it then increments the index number of all the sheets.  I just copy to the end and then new sheet is the last index minus one.  I then rename the new sheet to a unique name so I do not need to use the index number.

Comment: Fair comment, but see my answer below to see I only copy before the final (hidden) sheet, using **Before:template** as the Copy argument. Then I know I will always leave the template sheet at the end.

Answer (score 0):

I have a working, fairly elegant solution that allows me to look for an output sheet by name (if it already exists in the output file) or create a new one from the "Template" CodeNamed (and hidden) sheet.
The logic below is essentially that I pass in the Workbook that I am writing to, plus obj_Type as an identifier for the type of output (which sheet to use, essentially), and then I loop through every sheet - I create a new one from the Template if needed:

```
private static xl.Worksheet GetOutputSheet(xl.Workbook wb, string obj_Type)
{
    xl.Worksheet template = null;
    foreach (xl.Worksheet ws in wb.Worksheets)
    {
        if (ws.CodeName == "Template") // Find the Template, it might be needed
        {
            template = ws;
        }
        else if (ws.Name.Contains(obj_Type)) // Find the object's sheet, if already present
        {
            return ws;
        }
    }
    template.Copy(Before:template); // Copy the template before itself and return the copy
    xl.Worksheet ws_new = (xl.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[template.Index - 1];
    ws_new.Visible = XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetVisible;
    ws_new.Name = obj_Type;
    return ws_new;
}
```